# Get Bitmap image details (such as width and height)

Tags: android, image, bitmap, imageview

How to get the image detail (name, width, height, size, etc) which is selected in image view

**I Generate ImageViewXML**

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**and get a function to put selected image from folder to that ImageView**

```
Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);

            //Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Its all working correctly without bug, when i want to get the image detail, such as name by using *String.valueOf(bitmap)* but it return with : *android.graphics.Bitmap@5280fcb4*

How to get that image detail ?

Comment: Try this `String filename = uri.getLastPathSegment();`

Comment: That not working, it return of _integer_ value, in my case is 30

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getBackground()).getBitmap();
int width = bitmap .getWidth();
int height = bitmap .getHeight();
```

Size of Image

```
 Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getBackground()).getBitmap();
 ByteArrayOutputStream bytestream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();   
 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytestream );   
 byte[] imageByte = bytestream .toByteArray(); 
 long lengthbmp = imageByte .length;
```

Comment: How about the image name ?

Answer (score 0):

```
String path = (String) imageView .getTag();
```

you can get the path of the image by this getTag() from that should get the name of image

Comment: it return with _null_ ,  
as i now, we need to Tag-it manually in **xml** file : _android:tag = "any name"_ ?